# Counting number of occurance of words from one file to another

Tags: python, data-science

I have 2 files: positive.txt (has a huge list of positive words) and tweet.txt (big file that contains tweets that we have to do analysis on)

We are suppose to read both files and see how many positive words occurs in the file. I did it where it creates 2 lists for both files and compares them to see the amount of positive words, but it only counts it once. Is there a way for it to loop thru and find all the occurrences for all the positive words?

This is what i have so far(counts it once - ignores other occurances)

```
positive_word=0
txt = open('tweet.txt','r')
pos_txt=open('positive.txt').read().lower().split('\n')

for i in txt:
    i=i.lower().replace(':','').replace('?','').replace(',','').replace('.','').replace('"',
         '').replace('!','').replace('(','').replace(')','').replace('\'',
         '').replace('\\','').replace('/','')
    tweet=i.split()
    for p in pos_txt: #might be here where it only loops once thru the pos_txt once..so one occurrence only
        if p in tweet:
            positive_word+=1
print(positive_word)
txt.close()
pos_txt.close()
```

I tried using .count() and other functions found on other answers but no luck :(
Any suggestions to count all the occurrence for the positive words in the tweet file?

Comment: How do you have the word stored in `positive.txt` ? if the text is somethin like: `word1\nword2\n...` you can split directly by `\n` doing `.split('\n')`

Comment: @JorgeMorgado oh i did not realize I can do that! The text is like a word for each line, just like what you said. I will edit it for efficiency

Comment: Your script counts in the integer variable `positive word` how often _any_ of the words in the positive list occur in _any_ line of `txt`. Is this not what you want?

Comment: @halloleo How often is like if for example "appropriate" occurs 5 times right? That's what i want, but when i run it, i got 200 while other people got 1000+ words. I feel like my logic is right, but the answer isnt right :(

Comment: I think it is still not clear what solution you ask for, but my advice is: (1) Create a small sample (`tweet.txt` with a few made-up lines) and check whether the result of the script for the small sample is what you want and (2) Check with debug prints in the outer `for` loop that in the original `tweet.txt` the lines are really _lines_ for the Python script.

Comment: @studentprogrammer after the `split('\n')` edit it had the same behavior?